# Histogram representation of a database

Tags: database-theory, differential-privacy

I'm reading though [*The Algorithmic Foundations
of Differential Privacy*](https://privacytools.seas.harvard.edu/files/privacytools/files/the_algorithmic_foundations_of_differential_privacy_0.pdf) and the authors define a database in a mathematically convenient way. Unfortunately I'm a little confused about what the definition actually means in practice.

From page 17 of the pdf:

> We will think of databases $x$ as being collections of records from a
> universe $\mathcal{X}$. It will often be convenient to represent databases by their
> histograms: $x \in \mathbb{N}^{\lvert\mathcal{X}\rvert}$, in which each entry $x_i$ represents the number of
> elements in the database $x$ of *type* $i \in \mathcal{X}$ (we abuse notation slightly, letting the symbol $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of all non-negative integers, including
> zero).

Suppose we have a sample database that looks like this:

| Row | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | 19 |
| 2 | Ray | 22 |
| 3 | Sue | 42 |
| 4 | Bob | 42 |

I'm pretty sure each $x$ is just some combination of all rows of the database (say rows 1,3, and 4 or only row 1). I'm not at all clear what "*type* $i$" means. Is each *type* a row so that a database of rows 1, 3, and 4 would be $x = \{1, 0, 1, 1\}$? Or is *type* a level in the database; e.g. *type* $1$ is "Age 19", *type* $2$ is "Age 22", *type* $3$ is "Age 42", *type* 4 is "Tom", *type* 5 is "Ray", *type* 6 is "Sue", *type* 7 is "Bob". Thus the histogram representation is $x = \{1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1\}$?

To summarize my questions: What would the histogram representation $x$ be for a database with rows 1, 3, and 4? What are the possible values of $i$ in this $\mathcal{X}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you went wrong right from the start. $x$ is the database.  In this case, if the database is shown in that table, $x$ is the set of all rows shown in the table above.  If $x$ is a database with just rows 1, 3, and 4, then $x$ would be those set of three rows.

Now they recommend representing a set as a histogram.  To do that, we need to have a "universe" $\mathcal{X}$ of all possible rows that could ever occur (including both rows that do occur in the database as well as rows that don't occur in the database but could have).  Then, $x$ is a vector that records a count of how many times each of those possible rows actually occurs in the database.  If the possible row doesn't occur in the database, its count is 0; if it occurs once, its count is 1; and so on.  You then put those counts into a vector.

The possible values of $i$ are all possible rows in the universe $\mathcal{X}$.

Comment: Okay excellent, so a database with rows 1, 3, and 4 would have histogram vector $[1, 0, 1, 1] $ and a database with rows 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4 would have histogram vector $[1, 0, 3, 2] $? Could we say $x=[1, 0, 3,3]$ or is that bad database notation?

Comment: @robtimus_prime, yes, if by rows 1,3,4 you mean the 1st, 3rd, and 4th possibilities in the universe.  $x=[1,0,3,3]$ corresponds to a database with rows 1,3,3,3,4,4,4.